# How could I make xsl:value-of dynamic?

Tags: php, xml, xslt

Consider, that `<xsl:value-of select="@select"/>` outputs `/root/name`. The evaluated expression I want to pass to `value-of`, so it selects particular value in XML.

Whole code I want to make work:

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <xsl:value-of select="/root/name"/>
    <name>Foo</name>
</root>
```

**XSL:**

```
<xsl:template match="xsl:value-of">                                                                                                                                                                        
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">                                                                                                                                                                          
        <xsl:attribute name="select">
            <xsl:value-of select="@select"/>
        </xsl:attribute>                                                                                                                                                
    </xsl:element>                                                                                                                                                                                         
</xsl:template>
```

**Desired output:**
`Foo`

But it outputs nothing or with another solution it outputs just `/root/name`.

Is it even possible to make this code work? I use XSLT 1.0.

Thanks

Comment: Please post a reproducible example, including XML input and the expected output - see: [mcve].

Comment: @michael.hor257k Edited :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your input is not XML: you cannot have a prefix without binding it to a namespace.

More importantly, the value of the `select` attribute is the *string* `"/root/name"`.  You cannot evaluate a string as an *XPath expression* in XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 (unless your processor happens to support some sort of an `evaluate()` extension function*).

I am not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish here, but I suspect you need to rethink your strategy. Perhaps you need to start by generating a XSLT stylesheet from the input document, then apply that stylesheet to the input in second pass.

---

(*) For example, using either the `libxslt` or the `Xalan-J` processor you could process the following **well-formed** input:

**XML**

```
<root xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:value-of select="/root/name"/>
    <name>Foo</name>
</root>
```

with the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
extension-element-prefixes="dyn">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <results>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="xsl:value-of"/>
    </results>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xsl:value-of">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="dyn:evaluate(@select)"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to obtain:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
  <result>Foo</result>
</results>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, [dynamic evaluation of XPath expressions](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dynamic-xpath) requires XSLT 3.0.